# Read excel files in C# without using third party dlls/oledb/interop/sdk

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2005

I want to read excel files in C#. I dont want to use following things while reading:

1. ThirdParty dll( My client is not allowing me to use third party dll )
2. SDK(Same as above reason as am not allowed to download)
3. Not allowed to use interop/oledb as in target server there is no office installed.
4. OpenXml

Note: Am using vs 2005.

Please suggest me anything else>>

Thanks in advance,
Sanjay

Comment: what have you attempted?

Comment: Save the file as a CSV file and use [Microsoft.VisualBasic.TextFieldParser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx) to parse it.

Comment: OP stated they can't use third party DLLs.

Comment: I've never understood this fear of third party libraries. It's almost like some people think unless you went directly to the published spec and interpreted its content uniquely for your exact task then you must be cheating and weakening their network for hackers. Maybe your client can change their mind if you remind them that Microsoft spent millions of dollars on lawyers to prevent people from directly manipulating office formats. At least then you might get to use the interopt libs.

Comment: What version are the Excel files? The newer ones are XML based and somewhat easier to process. The older ones are proprietary and much more difficult to get at and you will definitely need a library.

Comment: Why do you put together OleDb with Interop? They are not the same thing. You can use OleDb (part of the NET.Framework) to read Excel Files and you don't need Office installed. Interop instead requires the presence of Office on the target machine

Comment: Why can't use you use OpenXml? Seems this an official MS library, so...

Comment: The only option you leave open is: you download the official specs from MS and implement them yourself - this will take several manyears and is rather error-prone...

Comment: @Yahia "*several many years*" - to implement your own import? I'd say that's *slightly* exaggerated...

Comment: @James "manyears" is is not "many years", it is just a word to account for the situation where you one versus many developers working on it... and: depending on which Excel versions you must support (esp. the older/binary XLS) you might well need 5-10 years with one developer...

Comment: @Yahia ah sorry misread that! Regardless though, 5-10 years for a single import is pretty over-exagerrated, even for 1 developer. You could write a simple excel import in less than an hour it all depends on the OP's needs and complexity of what they are trying to do.

Comment: @James it seems to me that you never the specs from MS... plase show me anyone writing an Excel import purely based on the specs for the binary XLS format (not XLSX) in less than one hour...

Comment: @Yahia I don't want to hijack this post like I said a "*simple*" import I never mentioned anything about the binary format in particular. Point being, I am *pretty* sure any half decent developer could write an Excel import in less than 5-10 years given it's purely for them and not going to be a 3rd party tool used by other people.

Comment: @James since we clearly have different pesepctives of what a robust import of a binary Excel file requires: let us agree to disagree...

Answer (score 2):

As I have said in my comment, using OleDb is not the same thing that Interop.
OleDb is part of the NET framework and, if your customer uses your application, it has already the Framework installed and running. So this example could be of help to demonstrate the fact that OleDb could read your target excel file without Office installed.

In this example I have a simple worksheet with three columns (and headers in the first line)
The first and second column are simple text column while the third contains numeric values

```
try
{
    string con = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\temp\test.xls;Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;'";
    using(OleDbConnection connectin = new  System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(con));
    {
        connectin.Open();
        OleDbCommand command = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("select * from [Sheet1$]", connectin);
        using(System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (dr.Read)
            {
                if(dr.HasRows)
                {
                    Console.Write(dr[0].ToString() + " ");
                    Console.Write(dr[1].ToString() + " ");
                    Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt32(dr[2]));
                }
            } 
        }
    }
}
catch(Exception ex) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString()); 
}
```

Comment: Hi, Does this work even my IIS machine where I deploy my code does not have Office installed.? If so, that actually answers my question. I have already implemented this in local and its working fine.

Comment: The only requirement with XLS is NET Framework. However a warning is mandatory here. Things are a bit more complicated with 64bit OS and TargetPlatform=AnyCPU. But this is another question